# Textfield width doesn't change in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to place textfield right next to a label. Instead of that textfield places under the label and fills one row. I tried to give column like JTextfield(10) but that didnt worked too. Is this about the layout i'm using?

```
public class guessTheNumber extends JFrame{

private JLabel info, info2, info3;
private JTextField input;

public guessTheNumber(){

    super("Guessing Game");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));

    info = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000.",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(info);

    info2 = new JLabel("Can you guess my number?",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(info2);

    info3 = new JLabel("Please enter your first guess:");
    add(info3);

    input = new JTextField("",10);
    add(input);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    guessTheNumber gtn = new guessTheNumber();
    gtn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gtn.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    gtn.setSize(500, 200);
    gtn.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, why are you using a 6 by 3 grid layout?  Do you have 18 elements to put into your JFrame?

Comment: The program hasn't finished yet. I will be using 18 elements. How is it relative with my question?

Comment: For the Grid Layout, it will fill the first row with the 3 labels.  The second row will be the JTextField in the first column position.  This would be the expected behavior of a 6 row x 3 column grid layout.  Try changing it to `new GridLayout(6,4)` for a second and you should see the textfield next to the label

Comment: No that doesn't work too. I have tried nearly everything but i couldn't  move that textfield.

Comment: Oh, whoops, didn't see that.  Try using `JPanel`.  That is, add the JPanel to the JFrame and then set the layout manager of the JPanel.  You know, `JPanel jp = new JPanel(); add(jp); jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));`  Just remember you have to add the labels and textfield to the panel now and not the JFrame

Comment: Panel works out fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `JPanel`. That is, add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` and then set the layout manager of the JPanel. You know,

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
add(jp); 
jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3));
```

Just remember you have to add the labels and textfield to the panel now and not the JFrame

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that changing the initialization to `GridLayout(6,4)` does not work.

If you want `info3` and `input` to be displayed together you could try the following excerpt:

```
info3 = new JLabel("Please enter your first guess:");
input = new JTextField("",10);

// Combine both components in a sub-container
JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
containerPanel.add(info3);    
containerPanel.add(input);

// Add the container to the guessTheNumber
add(containerPanel);
```